# How to use Python to put a CSV list of ips in iptables / IP Sets?

Tags: python, bash, csv, iptables

I would like to use [this CSV file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/client9/ipcat/master/datacenters.csv) to block all IPs from the list. The entries in the CSV file are IP ranges. How do I seperate the IP ranges from text, and add those IP ranges to the `iptables` with the rule to drop all connections with those IPs.

Btw, I think this is better to use for large ip ranges, http://ipset.netfilter.org/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You will need python [netaddr](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netaddr) module for that

```
import netaddr

with open('ipranges.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        startip,endip=line.split(',')[:2]
        print 'iptables -I INPUT -s {} -j DROP'.format(netaddr.iprange_to_cidrs(startip, endip)[0])
```

Comment: so I download the csv file, change the file extension from csv to txt, and then I execute that script en every IP range in that file will be added to the IP Tables?

Comment: Firstly, you need to install netaddr module. Then lauch a script - just change filename to the actual file you have. It will print out a bunch of netfilter rules. Then you just pass them to bash.

Answer (score 0):

maybe take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html to manipulate your ip addresses. ipaddress.summarize_address_range(first, last) could be nice to generate the iptables rule.